# Does Java 7 Hotspot JVM use SIGRT* on Linux?

Tags: java, linux, multithreading, signals

We have a java service that is loaded in a native daemon process on Linux. This daemon process blocks most signals and installs its own signal handlers since this process is a generic mission critical application. This is also a multi threaded application that leverages pthreads heavily and the HotSpot JVM is loaded in one of the threads.

After upgrading to Java 7 JVM on 64bit Linux (SLES, RH), we noticed that a `ServerSocket` waiting for connection doesn’t get signalled when the socket is closed.  As per the [JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/ServerSocket.html#close%28%29), any thread currently blocked in `accept()` will throw a `SocketException` and that way we close the listening sockets when the service shuts down.  We suspected the way we handle signals in the native process since we had similar experiences years back and it turned true.

In our native process, we block signals as given below(pseudocode).  We do install our own handlers using `sigaction()` which is not shown below.

```
sigset_t    set;
sigfillset(&set);
sigdelset(&set, SIGTRAP);
sigdelset(&set, SIGSEGV);

/* Remove following signals as it appears to be used by JVM */
for (int s = SIGRTMIN; s <= SIGRTMAX-4; s++) {
    sigdelset(&set, s);
}

if ((err = pthread_sigmask(SIG_BLOCK, &set, 0)) != 0) {
    err_warn(“Unable to block signals: %d”, err);
}

/* pthread_create() for LoadJVM calls and continue. 
   Threads are detached and hence no join()          */

/* Read current mask */
pthread_sigmask(SIG_BLOCK, 0, &set);

/* Wait on these signals */

while (bshutdown == false) {
    if ((sig = sigwaitinfo(&set, &info)) == -1) {
        /* something unexpected happened */
    }
    switch (sig) {
        /* Do something */
    }
}
```

What we found with the new JVM is, Java ServerSockets don’t get notified when they are closed if we remove SIGRTMAX-2 and SIGRTMAX-3 from the set.  Currently, we add these two signals and call pthread_sigmask(SIG_UNBLOCK, &set, 0) in the thread that loads JVM to resolve the issue.

**My questions are:**

1. Does anyone know if JVM uses these signals.  [JavaDoc on handling
   signals](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/webnotes/tsg/TSG-VM/html/signals.html)
   doesn’t list them.
2. On Linux (tested on x86_64 kernel 2.6.32,
   3.11.6), reading current signal mask (`pthread_sigmask(SIG_UNBLOCK, 0, &set)`) doesn’t return the current mask.  `set` is just 0.  Has
   anyone seen this behaviour?  It works fine on OSX and Solaris.

Comment: You might use `strace` to find out....

Comment: You might also try grepping the OpenJDK source for the signal name in question, or possibly the POSIX signal function names.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the suggestion to use `strace`.  Though I used `strace` to see how JVM is blocking signals, I didn't think of checking how the socket is closed.  This is what I found..

```
[pid  5525] rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, [QUIT], NULL, 8) = 0
========== Waiting for 30 sec before shutdown ==========
========== IP : 0.0.0.0, Port : 9999 ==========
[pid  5525] rt_sigaction(SIGRT_30, {0x7f8844015200, [], SA_RESTORER, 0x7f884de779f0}, NULL, 8) = 0
[pid  5525] rt_sigprocmask(SIG_UNBLOCK, [RT_30], NULL, 8) = 0
========== Shutting down ==========
[pid  5516] tgkill(5515, 5525, SIGRT_30 <unfinished ...>
[pid  5525] --- SIGRT_30 {si_signo=SIGRT_30, si_code=SI_TKILL, si_pid=5515, si_uid=1000} ---
[pid  5525] rt_sigreturn()              = -1 EINTR (Interrupted system call)
[pid  5516] <... tgkill resumed> )      = 0
```

which means, `SIGRT_30 (SIGRTMAX_2)` signals the listening socket when its closed.